# Maximal Ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3-x^2y, xy^2+xy+x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

To find the ideals of this ring, I was hinted to write $x^3-x^2y = x^2(x-y)$ and $xy^2+xy+x+1 = x(y^2+y+1) + 1$. My broad understanding is that I should try to mod out one variable at a time, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Since you're working over $\mathbb C$, this is basically equivalent to solving the simultaneous system of equations due to the ideal-variety correspondance. To further simplify, you can replace the ideal with it's radical. Can you use these to make some progress?

Comment: Your hint is unclear. If $x\not \in \mathfrak{m}$ then $x^2(x-y)\in \mathfrak{m}$ gives $x-y\in \mathfrak{m}$ so 
$xy^2+xy+x+1\in \mathfrak{m}$ gives $x^3+x^2+x+1\in \mathfrak{m}$ 
so that one of $x+1,x+i,x-i\in\mathfrak{m}$.